# ¿Cómo traducir al español "second wind"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

El término `second wind`, referido al sueño, es un fenómeno por el cual alguien que está cansado y a punto de caer dormido recibe "nuevas energías" si no se va "a tiempo a dormir" que le dificultan, paradójicamente, poderse dormir más adelante.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_wind_(sleep)) lo explica así en su versión anglosajona:

> Second wind (or third wind, fourth wind, etc.), also occasionally referred to as the wake maintenance zone, is a sleep phenomenon in which a person, after a prolonged period of staying awake, temporarily ceases to feel drowsy, often making it difficult to fall asleep once it happens.

Esto no implica [desvelarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DXshldX%7CDXtqSSD) o despertarse una vez que estás dormido. Es simplemente que, si no te vas a tiempo a dormir (cuando te viene el sueño y el cansancio) te "reactivas" y te puede luego costar más conciliar el sueño, aunque antes estuvieses a punto de dormirte y ahora sea incluso más tarde.

Este fenómeno se ve con claridad en los niños (los adultos a veces ignoramos esos breves momentos de cansancio por culpa de todo lo que tenemos o queremos hacer justo antes de acostarnos). Un niño que a las siete de la tarde está que se cae, y que podría irse perfectamente a dormir, si no lo hace se "reactiva" y luego aunque sean las 10 de la noche está "tan cansado" que no consigue dormirse.

Estoy seguro de que en español no se aplica la traducción literal "segundo viento". ¿Existe algún término en español para nombrar este fenómeno?

Comment: Esa expresión se usa también hablando de ejercicio y se traduce como "segundo aliento". En el caso del sueño no tengo ni idea, en mi entorno se usa para los niños *pasado de vueltas* o *pasado de rosca* como dice @pablodf76

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La expresión que he oído siempre usar en mi entorno es "**irse el sueño**":

> Le dejé la *tablet* al niño en el coche para que aguantara hasta llegar a casa, y ahora **se le ha ido el sueño** y no quiere acostarse.
>   Estaba tan cansado que casi me quedaba dormido, pero entre unas cosas y otras **se me fue el sueño** y ya no me dormí hasta pasada la medianoche.

Answer (score 5):

En México, por lo menos, se dice

> Se le espantó el sueño.

No encontré *espantar* en el DRAE, pero [Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/espantar) da:

> Ahuyentar, hacer que alguien se asuste y huya

Y da una expresión: "espantar el hambre"

Pero esto solo funciona con el context del sueño, que señalaste en la pregunta.  El otro uso de "second wind," que se le da al atleta al superar el cansancio, por ejemplo, sería diferente.

---

El [DRAE dice](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GUCz8Zj)

> ahuyentar a personas o animales

Comment: Espantar en el DRAE: http://dle.rae.es/?id=GUCz8Zj

Comment: Igual en Colombia.

Comment: @blonfu - gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Además de *irse el sueño*, suelo escuchar *pasarse de vueltas*, aunque es más una explicación que una afirmación del fenómeno en sí: alguien se quedó despierto pese a que tenía mucho sueño, sea trabajando, o charlando, o muy ocupado en alguna cosa que requiere su atención, y después descubre que no tiene más sueño. Es más algo de adultos, aunque de niños que juegan y hasta de bebés he oído que están *pasados de vueltas*. Digo que es más una explicación porque generalmente se debe aclarar:

- *Se pasó de vueltas y ahora no se duerme.*
- *Está pasado de vueltas y no le entra el sueño.*

Al que no puede dormir ni quedarse quieto porque estuvo muy activo se le dice que está *acelerado*.

- *Este chico está muy acelerado, ya no se duerme más.*
- *Quedé muy acelerado, no tengo nada de sueño.*

Comment: Yo también digo *pasado de vueltas*.